# Getting values from arraylists and saving

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, arraylist

Need help in getting values from arraylist then save to another arraylist (which is in another class file)

Comment: What did you try? Where are you failing? What are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: *"Need help"*  Need question.  As well as the answers to the 4 questions asked by @npinti  Voting to close as 'not a real question' since SO is a Q&A site, not a 'tutor me in detail' site.

Answer (score 3):

use `Intent` for passing value to another class(extends activity) `intentObj.putExtras()` will help.

to put:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("hello");
arrayList.add("there");
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondClass.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("pass_list", arrayList);
        startActivity(intent);
```

to get

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("pass_list");
```

Comment: i have no idea how to do that :\

Answer (score 0):

Use `get(index)`, `set(index, object)`, `insert(index, object)` and `add(object)` methods for this.

Example:

```
List<String> list0 = new ArrayList<String>();
list0.add("this");
list0.add("is");
list0.add("an");
list0.add("answer");

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add(list0.get(1));
list1.add(list0.get(3));
list1.insert(1, list0.get(0));
```

The resulting list1 will be: "is", "this", "answer".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection class's addAll method to add all elements of an arraylist to another.

See the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29